# jQuery child element mouseenter mouseleave

Tags: jquery, mouseenter, mouseleave

Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/FdT23/4/

The goal is that when you hover your mouse over the black box, the gray rectangle on the bottom will fadeIn and when you mouse out, the rectangle with fadeOut.  But if I mouseover the gray rectangle, it disappears.  I want it to stay visible.

Please assist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.mouseleave` instead

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#box').mouseenter(function(evt){

        $('#rect').fadeIn(300);

    });

   $('#box').mouseleave(function(evt){

        $('#rect').fadeOut(300);

    });

});
```

Updated JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FdT23/5/

Comment: In my case I had to set the z-index of the child element to 1, because it was absolutely positioned.  Don't know why, 'cause this aways holds true.

Answer (score 0):

try this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/F5BTE/)

Hope it helps. Used .hover instead.